# features type summary and progressbarwidget: percentage that the value of each row represents in relation to the sum of all values

Tags: extjs, grid, widget, extjs5

In a grid with features type summary and progressbarwidget, is it possible to display in progressbarwidget the percentage that the value of each row represents in relation to the sum of the all values (in the feature summary)?

FIDDLE: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1t4m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `onWidgetAttach` for any post-processing, and can sum values from the store itself. Using these, you can add the following to your widget column:

```
  onWidgetAttach: function(col, widget, record) {
      var sum = col.up("grid").getStore().sum("value")
      widget.setValue(record.get("value")/sum)
  }
```

As demonstrated by this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1t4v)

Comment: I edited my fiddle with new values. With some values the sum of the percentage does not add up to 100%. Is it possible to change the percentage (for example to 23.5%) to get more accurate values?

Comment: After cange config textTpl: [ '{percent:number("0.0")}%'],   e get 26,0%. However the result of the operation is still not accurate

Comment: @josei It looks like it may be the percent function that's rounding it. To get around it you can do `{value:number("0.0")*100}%` instead - I updated the fiddle to reflect this. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Works much better. Great and simple solution. Thanks again Jaimee.